# Complex vector on Block sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, hilbert-space, density-operator

I've the following problem. Given this vector on a 3D complex space:
 $$\\\\
 {\phi_{1}} = 
\begin{matrix}%
1/2(-1, & i\sqrt{2}, &1)^{T}
\end{matrix}\\
$$
Is it possible to draw it on the Block sphere? It is not clear to me the fact that the coordinates are complex.

Comment: Welcome to PSE. This question does not meet the requirements here, and it looks like a Mathematics question. Please provide some physics context, or migrate it to Math SE.

Comment: In any case, it's not at all clear what's being asked. Presumably you mean the Bloch sphere, which is a way to represent computed vectors in two dimensions. What makes you think that there are equivalent representations in higher dimensions?

Comment: Yes . I mean the Block Sphere where two dimensional qubits are located. The problem is that a 3D vector (x,y,z) under standard transformation rules for spherical coordinates, can be represented on the Block sphere since thare is the normalization constraint which reduced the dimension of a vector to two .components. My question is related to the fact that the vector (normalized) is defined in a complex space.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably your vector stands for a three-dimensional quantum state. The Bloch sphere is really only useful for two-dimensional quantum states, as commented by Emilio Pisanty.

Theoretically, there is an equivalent description to the Bloch sphere for three dimensional quantum states, but it is not useful for visualization as it is an eight dimensional sphere!

What's going on with the Bloch sphere is that two dimensional quantum states evolve through a unitary transformation in the group $SU(2)$, which acts as a matrix group on the two dimensional vectors expressing the quantum state as a $2\times 1$ vector of superposition weights with respect to a chosen orthonormal basis (*e.g.* orthogonal linear light polarizations). Locally, the group $SU(2)$ is isomorphic to group $SO(3)$ of three dimensional rotation matrices, and these are defined by their action on the 2-sphere, which we call the Bloch sphere in physics (or the Poincaré sphere in optics). Every state in 2D quantum space can thus be represented as a point on this sphere, modulo a phase delay of $-1$ (the two states $\pm\psi$ always become identified to the same point).

In three dimensions, the group $SU(3)$ acts on three dimensional vectors like yours. Locally, this is the same as a (small) subgroup of the eight dimensional rotation operators $SO(8)$, which acts on the eight dimensional sphere. In this case, any state becomes identified with its two multiples by the two, nonentity complex cube roots of 1 (analogously with the 2D case, where states are identified with their multiples by square roots of 1, *i.e.* $\pm1$).

So we could in theory represent this vector on a high dimensional Bloch sphere, but no it would not be useful. Perhaps it could be useful to octopus physicists.